# Magento 1.9 - Página de produto configurável, botão de comprar aparecendo lá embaixo

Tags: magento

Tenho um trabalho em um projeto pessoal com o Magento 1.9.

Instalei a base de exemplo, ele está funcionando sem problema algum nas suas funcionalidades. Mas o layout da página de um produto configurável está estranha. As opções configuráveis exemplo: Cor e tamanho. E o botão de comprar, estão ficando lá embaixo depois das fotos do produto.

Porém, em um produto configurável da base de exemplo. O layout está normal, com as opções de "cor" e "tamanho" em um bloco logo abaixo do nome do produto e preço.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Eduardo. Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

geralmente problemas de layout sao decorrentes de codigo CSS.

quando vc experimenta um novo tema, o problema persiste?

o problema ocorre com todos os produtos configuraveis que voce cria? ou apenas com alguns produtos criados por vc?

pois eh possivel q na descricao/titulo do produto vc tenha inserido um caracter invalido q esta quebrando o codigo.

sucesso ai.